# Parsing Text Files with Table/Columns on Top Rows and Records in Bottom Rows in Python

Tags: python, sql, parsing

Trying to parse a flat file with table definitions and columns on top of the file and the actual records below that. There is an indicator that differentiates if it is a record or table column key row.

Below is an example of how the data looks.

```
TABLE INDICATOR COLUMN COLUMN.....
TABLE INDICATOR RECORD RECORD.....


claim_tbl   1   claim_id    error_id    error_code
claim_notes_tbl 1 note_id   claim_id    biller_cd
job_parameters  3 ARCHIVE   FILEPATH    
claim_tbl   4   123 1234    401
claims_notes_tbl    4   1   123 101
```

I want to read in records into a staging table like this. Any suggestions on a proper way to do this? Good way to utilize the indicator? Any help is much appreciated

```
claim_tbl   
claim_id    error_id    error_code
123           1234         401
```

Comment: to read the file you could use csv or pandas library. I prefere pandas. Than once you can handle the table with python  you can use pandas even for sql stuff though. Also looking at Pyalchemy could help

Comment: You could use `grep` to extract all of the `claim_tbl` rows to one text file, all of the `claim_notes_tbl` rows to another text file, etc., then use `cut` to drop the first two columns from each of those files.  Then, if the column headers always precede the data in your original file, you should have a set of text files that you can import to the database with any number of tools.